# What do you use to connect simple battery holders?

Tags: voltage, batteries, cases

I'm sorry for this very rudimentary question, I'm completely new to this hobby.

I need to have a ~30V power source and I want to buy 22 AA batteries and connect them in a series. I intend to use several of this holders:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-x-AA-2A-Battery-Holder-Box-6V-Case-W-lead-ON-OFF-Switch-Enclosed-Box-Snap-On-/130685755489?pt=AU_Electronics_Batteries_Chargers&hash=item1e6d7a6061

but the problem is I have no idea what to use to make them join together, I don't think glue would work. I suppose I could make a cut in the middle of the wires and solder a wire from one casing to another, however I would rather want something more comfortable.

So how do you guys connect your circuits?
Like I said I'm a total noob, and if I'm posting in the wrong forum (it seems to me like a more professional environment) I apologize in advance.

Also, if you have any suggestion of how I can achieve my goal in an easier or cheaper manner I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need such a large power source for?

Comment: Soldering the wires is perfectly fine, but have you considered other powering options? I'm quite sure there is a better way to achieve your goal. If you need a low current, somewhat high voltage source a DCDC converter starting from a lower voltage is probably the way to go. Maybe you can use a 12V small lead acid battery, that won't be much bigger than 22AA batteries, would be easier to mantain and would last ages more.

Comment: How much load current do you need? Will the load be a constant current, or will there be intermittent high current peaks? Is there a weight limit? Is there a size limit? What is your cost budget?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams- I was thinking about a small portable mosquito zapper.




Vladimir Cravero- Thank you very much(!) for the suggestion, I did not know about the converters and I think I would probably do just that- One 12V battery and one converter.

Comment: MarkU- The load current...I was reckoning about 150-200mah with a constant load (when triggered). No weight or size limit but the budget is as restricted as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Great googly moogly! That's a lot of AA batteries ... as other commenters have mentioned, that's a pretty cumbersome solution for power. A lead acid or even LIPO (if you have the necessary charging station for them) would work.

If you want to go through with your particular design (If you give more information on what you're try to acheive, I or others may be able to give different options), then yes, soldering the wires together would be the way to go. A hot glue gun is a pretty handy tool too for mounting your cases to ... whatever it is you're doing, if it doesn't need to be super rugged.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, indeed I have changed my original design thanks to Vladimirs Cravero suggestion.
However I would still like to know for future reference how can I conflate 2 electric wires together in an aesthetic and quick manner. I remeber how a few years back, when I installed this chandelier, I used some white... couplers?... which came with the box and merged several wires together. I was wondering what type of similar solutions are there for small time electronic arrays?

Comment: @temp222 Those are commonly called pigtails, but they're not something you typically use on smaller wires, esp. if they're intended to be permanent connections(though you can) For something like your project you would probably want it to be more permanent: solder the wires together and use a heat-shrink covering.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that if there are no comfortable connectors for small wires then soldering it is... I have another question perhaps you know by any chance... Im on ebay right now looking for a suitable wire is this ok?        http://www.ebay.com/itm/2roll-4m-1007-24AWG-Single-Conductor-Guitar-Harness-Wire-2KB-/321197562809?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ac8dddbb9

Comment: It's probably fine, but it depends on how much current you're going to put through it. 24AWG is pretty small, so it can't take much sustained current.